# trying to execute ipynb file in vscode for m1 mac but not working

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

I'm trying to use vscode for python in my m1 macbook pro (2021).

I've installed anaconda / vscode / and jupyter notebook extensions in vscode.

Trying to execute simple python code in ipynb file but it shows an error like this and not working :

[image: screenshot of error]

I've tried executing same code in original jupyter notebook (in anaconda navigator), and that works.

So I think it's problem of vscode ... while I cannot figure out why.

And for reference there are no empty cells in ipynb file. (Which seems to be general causation of this error message, according to Google)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting up your environment with Rosetta?

Comment: I met the same problem. Not sure what's wrong with VSCODE, it works fine with original Jupyter Notebook in browser.